# oracle create function with cursor which sums another function

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I have one situation with function and cursors here. I got function Fun_1 which returns me ref_cursor and this type of data :

`<SYSTEM_NAME=SPORT1,CASH_IN=1,   CASH_OUT=0,    NET_WIN=1,     VAUCHER=0>,` 
`<SYSTEM_NAME=SPORT2,CASH_IN=279,CASH_OUT=57.86,NET_WIN=278.71, VAUCHER=0.29>`,`<SYSTEM_NAME=SPORT3,CASH_IN=9.22,CASH_OUT=0.5,  NET_WIN=9.22,  VAUCHER=0>;`

Now I want to create function which will return SUM(CASH_IN), SUM(CASH_OUT), SUM(NET_WIN) and SUM(VAUCHER) from Fun1 function.

What I have to do to achieve this ? Thanks

Comment: Does your function return each line of this data as a string or the cursor who's output's records are like `<SYSTEM_NAME=SPORT1` .please explain clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear if `<SYSTEM_NAME=SPORT1` , `CASH_IN=1` etc are individual columns or part of the whole string returned from your function. if they are part 
of whole string, you may use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` like in the query below. Assumption here is that all values after `=` are going to be integers or decimals.

If they are individual column values, then you could simply use `SUBSTR(s,INSTR(s,'=') + 1)` on each column to get the value after `'='`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dee146/4)

```
WITH c
     AS (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(s, 'CASH_IN=([0-9.]+)',  1, 1, NULL, 1)  a,
                REGEXP_SUBSTR(s, 'CASH_OUT=([0-9.]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) b,
                REGEXP_SUBSTR(s, 'NET_WIN=([0-9.]+)',  1, 1, NULL, 1)  c,
                REGEXP_SUBSTR(s, 'VAUCHER=([0-9.]+)',  1, 1, NULL, 1)  d
         FROM   t)
SELECT SUM(a) AS sum_CASH_IN,
       SUM(b) AS sum_CASH_OUT,
       SUM(c) AS sum_NET_WIN,
       SUM(d) AS sum_VAUCHER
FROM   c;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dee146/4/0)**:

```
| SUM_CASH_IN | SUM_CASH_OUT | SUM_NET_WIN | SUM_VAUCHER |
|-------------|--------------|-------------|-------------|
|      289.22 |        58.36 |      288.93 |        0.29 |
```

Comment: They are part of the whole string.  What you get in your result is what I need, just I want to function returns me this, because that function is gonna be called in front-end to display those results. I need  new function which will SUM me returns from old function...

Comment: @civesuas_sine : please understand that we r not here to write the whole code for your application to run, we just help you from our experience, when u find  things difficult. I gave u an idea. If you want a function,you could just pass a cursor to this query as argument that function. You need to know how to do it. If you find this answer useful, mark it as correct.Thanks.